# Laravel Session lost after redirect

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, laravel-5.5

I am implementing a solution to do SSO using SAML2 with Okta. After I receive a request back from the IDP, I authenticate the user and save the user information in to a session. Somehow, I lose both the session info. and Authenticated user information after I invoke redirect('/home'). Any thoughts? I can paste the code as well if needed. I appreciate the help.

Here is the Code Snippet:
    **Kernel.php:**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
   'web' => [
       \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
       \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
       \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
       // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
       \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
       \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
       \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
   ],

   'api' => [
       'throttle:60,1',
       'bindings',
   ], ];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
   'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
   'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
   'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
   'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
   'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
   'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
   'saml2' => \Singh\SimpleSaml\Middleware\Saml2Middleware::class,];
```

This is from **web.php:**

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Here is the code from **SamlController:**

```
public function acs(Request $request) {
   $errors = $this->saml2Auth->acs();
   if (!empty($errors)) {
       logger()->error('Saml2 error_detail', ['error' => $this->saml2Auth->getLastErrorReason()]);
       session()->flash('saml2_error_detail', [$this->saml2Auth->getLastErrorReason()]);
       logger()->error('Saml2 error', $errors);
       session()->flash('saml2_error', $errors);
       return redirect(config('saml2_settings.errorRoute'));
   }
   $user = $this->saml2Auth->getSaml2User();
   event(new Saml2LoginEvent($user, $this->saml2Auth));

   $redirectUrl = $user->getIntendedUrl();

   if ($redirectUrl !== null) {
       return redirect($redirectUrl);
   } else {
       return redirect(config('saml2_settings.loginRoute'));
   } }
```

This is a code from **Listener:**

```
public function handle(Saml2LoginEvent $event)
{
   if (!$event->getSaml2Auth()->isAuthenticated()) {
       Log::info('The user is not authenticated');
       return redirect(config('saml2_settings.logoutRoute'));
   }

   $samlUser = $event->getSaml2User();

   $attributes = $samlUser->getAttributes();

   //check if email already exists and fetch user
   $user = \App\User::where('email', $attributes['email'][0])->first();

   //if email doesn't exist, create new user
    if ($user === null)
    {        
        $user = new \App\User;
       $user->email = $attributes['email'][0];
       $user->shortname = $attributes['shortname'][0];
       $user->firstname = $attributes['firstname'][0];
       $user->lastname = $attributes['lastname'][0];
        $user->save();
    }

   if (count($attributes) >= 4) {
       session()->put('email', $attributes['email'][0]);
       session()->put('shortname', $attributes['shortname'][0]);
       session()->put('firstname', $attributes['firstname'][0]);
       session()->put('lastname', $attributes['lastname'][0]);
   }

   session()->save();

   Auth::login($user, true);  }
```

Comment: Did anything come of this? I'm experiencing the same thing with 5.4.

Comment: I was able to make it work. You can review the source code from the following packages: https://packagist.org/packages/singh/simplesaml

Comment: Thanks for that. I figured out the issue on my end: the route I was redirecting to didn't have the appropriate auth middleware and so the session was reset. Moving the redirect route under the middleware fixed my issue. Thanks again!